# set css style with php dom

Tags: php, dom

i am looking at building my website with the [php dom](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) classes. supposing i already have a document with a body, if i add a div to the body like so:

```
$div = $document->createElement('div');
$document->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->appendChild($div);
```

is there a way to set a 'style' attribute for this element which has multiple entries? eg one which ends up looking like this:

```
<div style="top: 40px; left: 60px;"></div>
```

i know i could do this:

```
$div->setAttribute('style', 'top: 40px; left: 60px;');
```

but i want each aspect of the style to be accessible without parsing the value through regex. this is because i would like to access the 40px value easily in other parts of my code.

Answer (score 3):

[XML Attributes are used to associate name-value pairs with elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Attribute) DOM does not (and cannot) know that you put CSS in there. That is because DOM is for arbitrary XML applications and not just for XHTML. CSS is a different Domain. So you have to parse it manually.

Alternatively, have a look at http://querypath.org. It [supports adding and reading style attributes directly](http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html#afaf2edbbd3305e34939c56d7a3cc8f10).

Comment: ah right. this rules out doing it natively with the php dom classes then. cheers

Answer (score 2):

What about the structure (written by yourself) like this:

```
$div = new Div();
$div->addStyle('top:', '40px;');
$div->addStyle('left:', '60px;');
print_r($div->Style)//for access of all style elements in case you need to modify them
$document->addElement($div);
//in case you need to modify an already added element, just
$document->Elements[17]; //or something similar
```

Hopefully you will find something useful :)

Comment: that looks like a nice clean way of doing it! i'm still a bit new to the php dom classes - how would i code my `Div` class to make sure that when i do the `$document->addElement($div);` it will not crash?

Answer (score -1):

set a class for current element with setAttribute and add custom css to style.css file